# How does Watson Conversation handle plurals?

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm just getting started with Watson Conversation and I have a basic question. I set up an intent named #play with several user phrases like "Please play the recipe notes" and "Read me the recipe notes".  Do I also have to account for the singular version, e.g., "Please play the recipe note"?  In other words is there an easier way to account for singular and plural input from the user?  I found this question relative to regular expressions: [Does watson conversation intents and entities support regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619629/does-watson-conversation-intents-and-entities-support-regular-expressions) which seems to indicate that the only way to handle this is to enter the singular version in the intent and then add a input.text.matches("notes") in the dialog. Is that the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, newbie mistake.  After playing around with the dialogs and, more importantly, importing the car dashboard app, I realized that the Conversation service combines the intent and entity to determine what to do.  So, I adjusted the intent to have phrases like "Please read the", "Read the", etc.  Then the entities end up be "ingredient" with a synonym of "ingredients", "instruction" plus "instructions", etc.  And voila it works.  Turns out you can enter just "ingredients" and it still works.  If I'm still out in left field with this approach I hope someone with more experience will let me know...

Answer (score 1):

For Intents, you normally don't need to account for plurals.  So having just "Please play the recipe notes" in your Intent training is sufficient for recognizing "Please play the recipe note".  It's more important to have the more extreme variations for the Intents such as "Read me the recipe note" and "Could you read the recipe note."

For Entities, Watson Conversation doesn't currently support plurals, typos, etc in Entities so you'll need to add plurals as synonyms if you want the Entity to match.