# Watson conversation service validation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Is there any way of validating the user input which uses context variable?

My context variable stores the email address,so I would like the validation to check for the "@" sign.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: check this out-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619629/does-watson-conversation-intents-and-entities-support-regular-expressions

Comment: I am facing a problem like when i am using slots the responses is not coming to my android app but it's running fine in it's try it out section. what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the context variable with regex to extract the e-mail address, and after your code just validate the information, if the `variableEmail = context.mail`, do it... I cant help you with the code because you did not report your Programmation language.

But, if you want to saves the mail address in a context variable.
I made a conversation example so you know how to do it, here are the steps:

**Part I:**

[image]

**Part II:** 
[image]

**Part III**:
[image]

**The JSON files**

*Name example*:

```
 {
      "context": {
        "name": "<? input.text?>"
      },
      "output": {
        "text": {
          "values": [
            "Hi $name, please report your e-mail address."
          ],
          "selection_policy": "sequential"
        }
      }
    }
```

*Mail example*:

```
{
  "context": {
    "mail": "<? input.text.extract('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]+){1,}',0) ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Thanks very much, your name is $name and your mail is $mail."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

**And finnaly, the result is:**

[image]

If you want knows how to **validate** mail, search with the programming language you are developing the application and don't forget: the informations is saved inside: `context.name` or `context.mail`, according to *my example*.

Comment: Thanks a lot!Really helped me!

Comment: Could you please provide the JSON file if you don't mind :)

Comment: Hi,What does "selection_policy" :"sequential" mean?

Comment: IBM provide this if you want various forms of response in Watson. Examplo: Hi Sayuri! You can add: Hello Sayuri, etc. And finally this response is sequential or random, you configure inside IBM Watson developer cloud.

Comment: I guess this got released with the new update for conversation service

Comment: Exactly, this was recent, but I usually track all of IBM's services.

Comment: I am facing a problem like when i am using slots the responses is not coming to my android app but it's running fine in it's try it out section. what should i do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @TanmaySahoo, in this case, try to Ask a Question on Stack with your Android code and the problems that you're having.

Comment: Thanks @SayuriMizuguchi for your suggestion. I have been blocked from asking new questions in stack overflow. And i think this is the way to gain some developer's attention and i found you. I have also sent a mail to you through linked in regarding this.

Comment: I'll take a look ASAP.